# Avoid Functor Instance Boilerplate

Tags: haskell, functor, boilerplate

I have some datatype `Verb p` defined as such:

```
data Verb p =   Look          {getPreps :: p}
              | LookExtra     {getPreps :: p}
              | Touch         {getPreps :: p}
              | Smell         {getPreps :: p}
              | HearExtra     {getPreps :: p}
              | Hear          {getPreps :: p}
              | Taste         {getPreps :: p}
              | Pickup        {getPreps :: p}
              | PickupExtra   {getPreps :: p}
              | Move          {getPreps :: p}
              | MoveExtra     {getPreps :: p}
              deriving (Show,Ord,Eq)
```

I must make this datatype an instance of `Functor` at the very least. Hence:

```
instance Functor Verb where
  fmap f (Look a)        = Look (f a)
  fmap f (LookExtra a)   = LookExtra (f a)
  fmap f (Touch a)       = Touch (f a)
  fmap f (Smell a)       = Smell (f a)
  fmap f (HearExtra a)   = HearExtra (f a)
  fmap f (Hear a)        = Hear (f a)
  fmap f (Taste a)       = Taste (f a)
  fmap f (Pickup a)      = Pickup (f a)
  fmap f (PickupExtra a) = PickupExtra (f a)
  fmap f (Move a)        = Move (f a)
  fmap f (MoveExtra a)   = MoveExtra (f a)
```

If that isn't boilerplate, then I don't know what is. I can imagine this becoming a real pain if I have to progress to `Applicative Functors` and so on. Is there a better way to write this without changing the structure of `Verb p` altogether? Due to the way I have written `Verb p`, It seems like I am doomed to declare an instance for each datatype constructor. Hopefully I can be proven wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out the `DeriveFunctor` extension. As the name hints, it allows you to simply add `Functor` to the `deriving` list. Unfortunately, this doesn't extend to `Applicative` and `Monad` because, unlike `Functor`, those generally don't have *one* way to define the instance, but multiple nonequivalent possibilities.

In your example, I'd simplify the data definition:

```
data VerbType = Look | LookExtra | ...
type Verb a = (VerbType, a)
-- or data Verb a = Verb { verbType :: VerbType, getPreps :: a }
```

Comment: `DerivingFunctor` is very useful, but for this case, you already have a functor instance (namely `((,) a)`) if you define the data type as suggested.

Comment: This is a very useful extension; I did not know about this. However, I think your second bit of advice (doing some light restructuring of my datatype) is probably more generally useful to my situation. Thank you very much.